# How make parallax scrolling window responsive with mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax.js

```
<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/1.jpg"></div>
```

In css

```
 .parallax-window {
min-height: 800px;
background: transparent;
```

i use parallax.js

i need to compatible scroll image with mobile please anyone help..

Comment: parallax.js is already responsive. Post your html so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

May Be You Could Make Use Of 
Libraries Like enquire.js(media queries)

https://ihatetomatoes.net/make-parallax-website-responsive/

Answer (score 0):

In your css file you will need to define the parallax class, then use the following to ensure the parallax image scales responsively:

```
@media(max-width:648px){.parallax{height: 300px}}
```